# Automatic Checkout with TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I recently moved to a new client where the source control system is TFS 2008.  I have been using Subversion for almost 4 years so this is quite a change for me.  One of the first things I noticed is that every time I try to modify a file Visual Studio (2008) tells me that the file is read-only.  I spoke to the guy in charge of TFS and he informed that I need to manually check-out that file before I can modify it.  So basically automatic checkouts aren't working for me.

The only advice I have gotten thus far is to enable it in Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment->Prompt for check-out.  Which didn't work - it was enabled already.  (Plus Visual Studio isn't even prompting me for a check-out - it just tells me the file is write-protected)

Is it possible that TFS is setup to not allow automatic checkouts? (I'm not allowed to touch the TFS setup - we have a whole department for that) Or am I just being blind?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like the solution isn't “bound” to the version control provider. From Visual Studio's main **File** menu, select **Source Control**, **Change Source Control…**. You'll see this dialog:

http://alinconstantin.members.winisp.net/webdocs/scc/Bindings1.png

Make sure the the server bindings are correct and that each solution/project is “connected”.

Comment: Thanks - don't know how the hell that happens - I check it out of Source Control and set the bindings the first time...

Answer (score 1):

TFS is of course able to automatically check out as soon as you start editing the file.

The option is under Source Control -> Environment -> Checked-in items

You should choose Editing: **Check out automatically** in the drop-down list.

Comment: Reading comprehension is important:  *The only advice I have gotten thus far is to enable it in Tools->Options->Source Control->Environment->Prompt for check-out. Which didn't work - it was enabled already.*

Comment: Yeah alright, sorry - only I suggested another option: Check out automatically. Could have worked!

Comment: Weeeeelllll.... I think he might have typo'd on that one.  I think he wouldn't be complaining that his files aren't automatically being checked out if he specifically set it to Prompt...

Answer (score 1):

Probably a strange case, but I found Visual Studio wouldn't do auto-checkout or prompt for checkout on edit if I was trying to edit an ascx or aspx file that had a resx file in the filesystem but not included in the project.  It just played the error sound and didn't give any message.  Deleting the resx files fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Bug.  There isn't a fix for it yet (at least I don't think).  I recorded my "workaround" (which is probably 3/4 voodoo but I can't repro to test what parts of this work) in a MSDN forum question that's the top hit on Google for this issue:

This is the #1 hit for "automatic checkout stopped working", so I am recording the solution for this in Visual Studio 2008.

This can happen when VS crashes.  It can also propagate from one user to another after a crash.

**Here are the steps to fixing this; follow them in this order and your problem will most likely go away.**

1. Check in everything
2. Close visual studio
3. Make sure every file is set to read only in the solution directory (set it on the root solution folder and configure it to propagate to children)
4. Search for all files under the root projet directory *.user and *.vssscc and delete them (this might be overkill; one or the other may be the culprit but deleting both types won't hurt you)
5. Open VS and load the solution
6. Check everything back out and then check everything back in

Answer (score 0):

this is the fix

http://d4dilip.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/automatic-file-checkout-is-missing-in-vs2010-and-tfs/